# Run job once at a specific time in future using queue_classic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, queue-classic

is there a simple way to run a job once at a specific time in the future using queue_classic and clockwork, something like delayed_jobs

```
class.delay(run_at: 5.hours.from_now).method(param)
```

Comment: Tagged your question with queue-classic, maybe someone can help =)

Comment: @Adbo Thanks, I haven't been able to solve it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with [Toro](https://github.com/tombenner/toro), which is another job queueing system that runs on Postgres and Ruby.

Here's an example:

`MyWorker.perform_at(5.hours.from_now, 'First arg', 'Second arg')`

Check out the [Scheduled Jobs](https://github.com/tombenner/toro#scheduled-jobs) section of the README for details.